# Live camera streaming with Nanohttpd in android

Tags: android, nanohttpd

I am developing an android project which send live camera stream to Nanohttpd server by using wifi,how can i achieve this,Is it possible?

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some code or ways which you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.. try bellow examples it's work for me.

[Use Android Phone as Webcam and Surveillance Camera](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/791991/Use-Android-Phone-as-Webcam-and-Surveillance-Camer)

[HTML5 Camera and Android](http://www.smartlab.at/articles/html5-camera-and-android/)

those examples are capable of streaming [MJPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG).
It uses NanoHttpd and extends it to support motion JPEG.